# Creating a "search" function in MS Excel

Tags: excel, search

I have a list of >100,000 diagnosis codes in a .XLS document and need to extract from this all codes that are relevant to a number of specific diseases.

What I would like to be able to do is include all 100,000 diagnostic codes in Column A, diagnostic labels in column B, and then have a "search term" cell (e.g. C1) in which I can write a word such as "fracture".

I would then like all the diagnostic codes including the string "fracture" to appear in column D.

Is there a simple way of doing this in Excel? I have looked online without much success but this might be because I'm not certain where to start. Conditional formatting hasn't helped as it's still unmanageable to scroll through 100,000 codes even if they are highlighted nicely.

Any initial thoughts or tips as to what I could try searching for would be very welcome.

Sample dataset:

```
238 Fracture of proximal humerus
202 Aortic stenosis
990 Chronic obstructive pulmonary disease
302 Hip fracture
182 Recurrent fractures
094 Marfan syndrome
298 Diabetic retinopathy
```

Comment: searching for "excel dynamic filter" results in http://trumpexcel.com/2015/01/dynamic-excel-filter/. I would probably make a PowerPivot or PivotTable instead with each word and the corresponding diagnosis next to it to make it easier.

Comment: Thanks - a really neat trick. I will have a play with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realize you didn't ask for a filter but if you are open to a slightly different solution this seems to work well. Column A title and values should start at cell `A2`. Then type your search term in cell `B1`. It will also filter with wildcards and is case insensitive (i.e. show `fracture`, `Fracture`, `fractures`, `Fractures`, `fractured`, `Fractured`).

```
Option Explicit
Sub Filter()

Dim MyArray() As Variant
Dim MyNewArray() As Variant
Dim i As Long
Dim item As Variant
Dim FilterRange As Range

With ActiveSheet
    Set FilterRange = .Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))
    MyArray = Application.Transpose(FilterRange)
    i = 0
    For Each item In MyArray
        If UCase(item) Like "*" & UCase(Range("B1")) & "*" Then             
            ReDim Preserve MyNewArray(i)
            MyNewArray(i) = item
            i = i + 1
        End If
    Next item
    .Range(FilterRange.Address).AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=MyNewArray(), Operator:=xlFilterValues
End With

End Sub
```

Additionally, you could add the following in the `Worksheet` object so you don't have to click a button to run the macro:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Not Application.Intersect(Target, Range("B1")) Is Nothing Then
    Call Filter
End If

End Sub
```

Honestly, you can achieve the same thing with `Filter` > `Text Filters` > `Custom Filter`. You can use wildcards, too. :)

Comment: Thanks. In this case it would take me a long time to use Filter > Text Filters > Custom Filter through the menu options - I'm facing 1000 individual searches through these 100,000 items and desperately looking for anything to make my life easier! Slai's link above (http://trumpexcel.com/2015/01/dynamic-excel-filter) which shows how to create a dynamic filter is also very elegant.

Answer (score 2):

We can use a helper column to find the matching rows.  In **E1** enter:

```
=MATCH("*" & $C$1 & "*",B:B,0)
```

and in **E2** enter:

```
=IFERROR(MATCH("*" & $C$1 & "*",INDEX(B:B,E1+1):INDEX(B:B,999999),0)+E1,"")
```

and copy down.  Column **E** tells us where the matches are..  Then in **D1** enter:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(A:A,E1),"")
```

and copy down:

[image]

This is a fairly standard way to do a **keyword search**.

Comment: That is a good way of doing a keyword search with a lot of rows, have to remember that one.

Comment: @TomSharpe  the important point is the cascading wildcard match .

Comment: Thanks, yes I get that - MATCH(...0) can only ever give one match, but you can get round it by restarting it just after the point where you left off.

Comment: @TomSharpe  you are exactly right..........that is the purpose of the `INDEX()` in column **E**

Comment: Thanks - all the suggestions here appear to work but I settled on this one in the end.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you want to search the term contained in C1 in column B.
You can try using this in A

```
=IF(C1<>"",IFERROR(FIND(C1,B1,1),0),0)
```

This will return a number if the text in C1 is present, else a 0.

You can then set D to be

```
=IF(A1>0,B1,"")
```

You will obtain this

[image]

Comment: You'd need to use SEARCH instead of FIND to match fracture with Fracture.

Answer (score 0):

I am putting the string to be searched for in the first row.

In row 2, I do a string match to get the first instance of a match for C1 in column A.

```
C2    =INDEX($A:$A,MATCH("*"&C1&"*",$A2:$A$100,0)+1)
```

Then find the next match starting from the array with row that matches C2 as the first row. I am fixing the last row as A100 which you can change.

```
C3    =INDEX($A:$A,MATCH("*"&$C$1&"*",INDIRECT("A"&MATCH(C2,$A:$A,0)+1&":A100"),0)+MATCH(C2,$A:$A,0))
```

Copy the formula down as required. Then copy columns across as required.

You can wrap the formula using IFERROR to suppress N/As.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can also used an advanced filter in Excel by going to Data|Advanced:-

[image]

Note that the column headers in C1 and D1 must match the column headers in A1 and B1.

You can also adopt a DIY approach with:-

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(B:B,SMALL(IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH($H$2,$B$1:$B$100000)),ROW($B$1:$B$100000)),ROW(1:1))),"")
```

assuming the search term is in H2, starting in say J2 and pulled down as necessary. This may be a little slow with 100K terms but is usable. Must be entered as an array formula with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>